# AlertDialog neutral button dismissing the dialog

Tags: java, android, dialog, gps

Although there is no mention of dismissing or closing my dialog box when the neutral button is pressed, my app still feels the need to close the dialog when it is pressed.

Any ideas why?

```
dialogBox = (AlertDialog) dialogBoxHandler.locationDialog();
dialogBox.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Use Current Location", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    EditText latitude = (EditText) dialogBox.findViewById(R.id.dl_et_latitude);
                    EditText longitude = (EditText) dialogBox.findViewById(R.id.dl_et_longitude);
                    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) MessageSelection.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    try {
                        Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                        double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                        latitude.setText(Double.toString(currentLatitude));
                        longitude.setText(Double.toString(currentLongitude));
                        Log.d(TAG, "Latitude " + currentLatitude + "  Longitude " + currentLongitude);
                    } catch (SecurityException e){
                        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                    }
                }
            });
 dialogBox.show();
```

Comment: question is not clear...did you want to dismiss the dialog in neutral button press?

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 No I don't want it to close

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out an OnShowListener was needed and it had to have the onClickListener defined within it. This would not work when trying to define the neutral button functionality when using the DialogBuilder or by setting the buttons functionality after the dialog has been created (and before it has been shown).

```
dialogBuilder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_location, null))
            .setNeutralButton("Use Current Location", null);

final AlertDialog locationDialog = dialogBuilder.create();

locationDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

            Button button = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    EditText latitude = (EditText) locationDialog.findViewById(R.id.dl_et_latitude);
                    EditText longitude = (EditText) locationDialog.findViewById(R.id.dl_et_longitude);
                    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    try {
                        Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                        double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                        latitude.setText(Double.toString(currentLatitude));
                        longitude.setText(Double.toString(currentLongitude));
                        Log.d(TAG, "Latitude " + currentLatitude + "  Longitude " + currentLongitude);
                    } catch (SecurityException e){
                        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: A working workaround. Both neutral and negative buttons call dismiss natively unless callback specified before showing the dialog is null.

Answer (score 0):

every button in AlertDialog will dismiss it
ONLY if you do:

```
mAlertDialog.setView(mButton);
```

a mButton click wont dismiss it

Comment: Is setView() not for setting the layout of the dialog?

Comment: it is,so if you want to execute on click in a AlertDialog w/o closing it thats the way to do it

Answer (score 0):

All AlertDialog buttons will close it. If you need a button and you want the AlertDialog not dismissing, you will have to use a custom view with the button inside.